# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

working on the Gatsby project with MDX files (around 500+ MDX files) and getting the following error. I have resolved the error locally using the NODE_OPTIONS command but also facing an error in Gatsby Cloud (using free ACC)

[image: gatsby cloude error]

> export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"

```
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of  C:\projectFolderName\website\.cache\_this_is_virtual_fs_path_\$virtual\async-requires.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.

⠇ Building development bundle
[=========================== ]   6.726 s 93/94 99% Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING jobs

<--- Last few GCs --->

[9976:000001988CB9E980]    95944 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 3788.6 (4135.7) -> 3788.1 (4126.0) MB, 406.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.200, current mu = 0.099) allocation failure; GC in old space requested[9976:000001988CB9E980]    96920 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 3804.8 (4142.6) -> 3804.7 (4130.4) MB, 934.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.099, current mu = 0.042) allocation failure; GC in old space requested

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF772162BCF node_api_throw_syntax_error+175519
 2: 00007FF7720E83A6 SSL_get_quiet_shutdown+64006
 3: 00007FF7720E9762 SSL_get_quiet_shutdown+69058
 4: 00007FF772B8FDD4 v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+116
 5: 00007FF772B7B132 v8::Isolate::Exit+674
 6: 00007FF7729FCF8C v8::internal::EmbedderStackStateScope::ExplicitScopeForTesting+124
 7: 00007FF772A0A26D v8::internal::Heap::PublishPendingAllocations+1117
 8: 00007FF772A072F7 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3367
 9: 00007FF7729F9A27 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2039
10: 00007FF772A103E3 v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath+2099
11: 00007FF772A10C8D v8::internal::HeapAllocator::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath+93
12: 00007FF772A195DA v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw+810
13: 00007FF772A2CA1D v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewHeapNumber<0>+685
14: 00007FF772A30EC8 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewRawTwoByteString+72
15: 00007FF7727D8924 v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten+724
16: 00007FF772B999ED v8::String::Utf8Length+141
17: 00007FF77210E521 v8::internal::Malloced::operator delete+18209
18: 00007FF772B4895D v8::internal::Builtins::code+248237
19: 00007FF772B48569 v8::internal::Builtins::code+247225
20: 00007FF772B4882C v8::internal::Builtins::code+247932
21: 00007FF772B48690 v8::internal::Builtins::code+247520
22: 00007FF772C2D471 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+558449
23: 00007FF6F3F5AF91
```